# Python Runtime error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable (Hackerrank excercise)

Tags: python, runtime-error, typeerror

I'm working on this excercise

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem

Python does throw in a Runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 36, in <module>
    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

---

I only programmed the climbingLeaderbord function, the rest of the code was already given to me. When I print the results, it shows me that my solutions are correct, but Python is still giving me the Runtime error. What did I do wrong?

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):
    for i in range(0, len(alice)):
        rank = 1
        scores_ident = 0
        for j in range(0, len(scores)):            
            if alice[i] < scores[j]:
                rank = rank + 1
                if j > 0 and scores[j] == scores[j-1]:
                    scores_ident = scores_ident + 1
        rank = rank - scores_ident
        print(rank)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    scores_count = int(input())

    scores = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    alice_count = int(input())

    alice = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: `climbingLeaderboard` doesn't `return` anything

Comment: Returning something doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: The problem description clearly states: *" It should return an integer array"* - so do exactly that

Comment: You're right, it worked now! Thanks!